# Fluent control writing like Telerik : Understanding the angle brackets translation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controls, viewengine

Here is a piece of class :

```
public class OneControl
{
    ...

    public OneControl Content(Action value) {
        ContentProperty = value;
        return this;
    }

    public void Render()
    {
        ContentProperty();
    }

    ...
}
```

Then I got this in my view :

```
<div id="pleaseHelpMe">
    <% OneControlInstance.Content(() => { %> 
        Some Mixed Stuff <%= Example%> Euros
    <% }).Render() %>
</div>
```

I would like to use this syntax in my UI library, I know how to implement this but I don't know HOW it actually works !

I understand that somewhere and somewhat a delegate is created and provided as an argument of the method Content, but can't find any information about this mecanism or technic.

Can you enlight me ?

PS : I'll change the title according to the anwser I get.

**Assumed current correct answer** :

The compiler translates the aspx code below into (symbolic translation for comprehension) :

```
<div id="pleaseHelpMe">
    <% OneControlInstance.Content(() => {
        ViewPageInstance.Response.Write("Some Mixed Stuff ");
        ViewPageInstance.Response.Write(Example);
        ViewPageInstance.Response.Write(" Euros");
    }).Render() %>
</div>
```

**Big thanks to Hogan !!**

Comment: That's a tasty piece of class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`() => { %> Some Mixed Stuff <%= Example%> Euros <% }` is the delegate.

In an an .NET aspx page stuff outside of `%> <%` (the html stuff) gets translated into `output.render(string)` when the aspx page is compiled.

So this is the same as the delegate code:

```
() => 
{ 
  output.render(" Some Mixed Stuff "); 
  output.render(Example); 
  output.render(" Euros "); 
}
```

---

**Prior comments:**

Not sure what you are asking.  `Action value` is the delegate.  From the docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

"Encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return a value."

and

"You can use the `Action(<T>)` delegate to pass a method as a parameter without explicitly declaring a custom delegate."

---

If you want your delegate to return a value you can use `TResult Func<in T, out TResult>`

Answer (score 1):

ContentControls have a ContentProperty [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentproperty%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which is essentially a delegate. Your class sets this value through a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) (essentially the `return this` part of the Content method) - which is just a way of making development easier, nothing super relevant in itself - and this delegate wille ventually be executed by the Render method, which is part of the control lifespan.

The bit you might be missing is that you're providing the delegate [action](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/anonymousMethods04022006141542PM/anonymousMethods.aspx) in your markup here:

```
<% OneControlInstance.Content(() => { %>   
        Some Mixed Stuff <%= Example%> Euros  
    <% }).Render() %>
```

The action is everything inside the content method call, i.e. `() => { stuff }` which you shoudl try and read as an anonymous function with arguments in between the parens and function code in between the braces.

Comment: I understand this, but who transforms %> Html stuff<% into a delegate ? Is it the view engine ? The compiler ?

Comment: `() => { %> Some Mixed Stuff <%= Example%> Euros <% }` is the delegate.  In an an .NET page stuff outside of `%> <%` (the html stuff) gets translated into output.render(string) when the aspx page is compiled. So this is the same as the delegate code: `() => { output.render("some mixed stuff"); output.render(Example); output.render(" Euros"); }`

Comment: OK, I see your point, nice ! However I think the interpretation comes from the view engine.

Comment: No the interpretation comes from the compiler.  Do you mean something else by interpretation?

Comment: I got the answer, this is the compiler.